# peewee mutithreading "database is locked"

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

I'm working on app which works in multiple threads and perform database operations parallel. While generally it works well, sometimes I get an exception that database is busy. I should say that it was quite complex task to create a compact reproducible example, but somehow I ended up with this:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from time import sleep
from random import random
from peewee import SqliteDatabase, Model, FloatField

db = SqliteDatabase("test.db", pragmas={"journal_mode": "wal"}, timeout=10)

class TestModel(Model):
    number = FloatField()

    class Meta:
        database = db

def func(number):
    with db.connection_context():
        with db.atomic():
            TestModel.create(number=number)
            sleep(number)

db.create_tables([TestModel])

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(func, random()) for _ in range(100)]

    for future in as_completed(futures):
        result = future.result()
```

This code throws an exception:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 3160, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params or ())
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\test.py", line 33, in <module>
    print(future.result())
  File "\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 438, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 390, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "\test.py", line 19, in func
    TestModel.create(number=number)
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 6393, in create
    inst.save(force_insert=True)
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 6603, in save
    pk = self.insert(**field_dict).execute()
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 1911, in inner
    return method(self, database, *args, **kwargs)
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 1982, in execute
    return self._execute(database)
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 2761, in _execute
    return super(Insert, self)._execute(database)
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 2479, in _execute
    cursor = database.execute(self)
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 3173, in execute
    return self.execute_sql(sql, params, commit=commit)
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 3167, in execute_sql
    self.commit()
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 2933, in __exit__
    reraise(new_type, new_type(exc_value, *exc_args), traceback)
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 191, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 3160, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params or ())
peewee.OperationalError: database is locked
```

I've added `sleep()` call into `db.atomic()` context just to simulate some complex operation with database which takes few hundreds of milliseconds.

I know that SQLite allows single writer at one period of time, so I've put all writing operations into `db.atomic()`, but for some reasons code inside this context throws exception that database is busy.

What am I doing wrong?

---

I know why this happens technically. As far as I understood, when thread does `.atomic()` call and some other thread are holding database for transaction, it waits until timeout and throw an exception. The question is .. why? It sleeps for less then second, timeout is set to 10 seconds, so there should be enough time to wait until database will be released and jump in. In real app transaction don't take even 100ms, but occasionally this exception happens.

---

This exception happens randomly on any atomic update in code. I even added logging to check how much time maximum takes any of my transactions and it's 81ms maximum, timeout set to 20 seconds and there are maximum 7 transactions happens per second, so I have no clue why it's dying internally. It'd be probably easier to switch database engine or switch to low-level `sqlite3`, but I have no intention to fight with this anymore.

Comment: WAL-mode has different failure mode than regular journal mode.

Comment: @coleifer, it doesn't matter. I've already tried to delete all pragmas and all the same. In real app it's just impossible to trace, as workflow based on network requests. Once it crushes on creating one model, other time on update compeletely another.

Comment: https://charlesleifer.com/blog/multi-threaded-sqlite-without-the-operationalerrors/

Comment: @coleifer, yes, thanks for the link, I've already found it in google. Unfortunately `SqliteQueueDatabase` can't completely prevent exceptions in my particular case. There is rare chance that second writer process will be executed. It does a single transaction, but it will lock a database which could cause same exception. After some tests and fix attempts I came to conclusion that SQLite is just not a proper database here. While project seems to be small, concurrent writes turns SQLite into a problem. I switched to PostgreSQL, with some query optimizations it demonstrates descent performance.

Comment: Read the section on transactions: https://charlesleifer.com/blog/going-fast-with-sqlite-and-python/ -- this should help if you do decide to use sqlite. I think you are probably just not using transactions cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is a single threaded database by nature.
to allow multithreading you should intialise sqlite with specific parameter
threaded true.
read more here: https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html
you can do this by set check_same_thread=False

Comment: You probably haven't noticed that I'm using [peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/) ORM, not standard sqlite module. I'm sure that internally it manages all necessary flags and parameters.

Comment: Its just a backend it uses the sqlite module, it will work. pass within the pragmas check_same_thread=False.

Comment: Of course it uses sqlite3 internally, but again, I'm sure that all setup required for multithreading is done. There's `thread_safe` argument in constructor and it's `True` by default.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found out that I did a **backup** by opening the database before closing the connection to database. It caused me this issue.
I moved the backup to the end of the python after all databases get a `.close()`:

`with open(file, 'rb') as f:` was locking the file 1/1000 times.

NOTE:
I found out the issue when looking at multiple logs and found all issues started at the specific date, where I added this file to my backing up mechanism.